# "no line items found" in user order

Tags: commerce

I have installed [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (7.x.1.8 version) but in user orders section when I select an order only price and total is shown. In despite of order details the message "no line items found" appears. What can I do on here to show order datails?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me via [this article](http://julian.pustkuchen.com/en/drupal-commerce-no-line-items-found-problem-invoices-some-circumstances).

The author propose to change the Commerce view settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem for anonymous users depending on the permission configuration you might have, the usual solution is to disable the SQL query rewriting for the affected view.

Check out these related issues in drupal.org

- https://drupal.org/node/1811972
- https://drupal.org/node/1276450
- https://drupal.org/node/1303194

Answer (score 0):

'Disable SQL rewriting' in the affected view:

1. Edit the view: in 'Advanced' select 'Query settings' 
   [image: Edit the view: in 'Advanced' select 'Query settings']
2. Select 'Disable SQL rewriting'
   [image: Select 'Disable SQL rewriting']